# A react-native application not rendering/routing to SignIn page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aws-amplify

I am using aws-amlpify-react-native to signin/signup and sign out of the app. All seem to be working fine except signout. When clicking on signout, the app is signed out but it displays the signup screen (This is the screen where the signout button exists) but it does not render the Signin page.

I extended the Greeting class and I also tried extending the AuthPiece class but this did not fix the issue. Below is a snippet of my Signup screen code that enables SignOut:

```
import {Greetings} from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
export default class MainScreen extends Greetings {
  signOut() {
    Auth.signOut()
        .then(() => { this.changeState('signedOut')})
        .catch(err => { this.error(err); console.log('error is .......' + err)} );
  }
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
   render(){
     return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ToolBar />
        <ScrollView style={styles.content}>
          <View style={[styles.container, styles.content]}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.buttonContainer]} onPress={() => this.signOut()}>
              <Text style={styles.signupText}>Sign out</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
     );
```

Comment: what is `this.changeState`?

Comment: Sean, this function is inherited from AuthPiece component and it changes state to signin, signedout, etc.
The source code for this component is here:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/aws-amplify-react/src/Auth/AuthPiece.jsx